# Printing hyperlink in PDF using PDF:Reuse in Perl Catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

Trying to use `PDF::Reuse` in Catalyst to produce simple documents. 
I have not found the syntax how to put http link into the pdf document in `Catalyst::View::PDF::Reuse` modul:
http://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::View::PDF::Reuse
When looking into single `PDF::Reuse` I expect to use in my template this syntax:

`[% pdf.prHyperLink(100, 100, 'Press this link', 'http://www.test.com') %]`

But it does not work. What is the correct syntax to put http link into pdf using `Catalyst::View::PDF::Reuse`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of PDF::Reuse the function for adding a hyperlink is prLink and not prHyperLink. Could that be the reason your template does not work?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I was not sure if I can use prLink from PDF::Reuse, whether Catalyst::View::PDF::Reuse can also handle it. Anyhow ... still not working for me in Catalyst, even this: [% pdf.prLink(100, 100, 'Press this link', 'http://www.test.com') %]